# React.JS working with two values in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to do math operation from two inputs. First update state and then add two values with newly updated state.

```
<input type="number" onChange={this.handleIncomeChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.income} />
```

This code isn't working: (result is always one number behind)

```
handleIncomeChange(e) {
    this.setState({income: e.target.value});
    this.state.resultMonth = +this.state.income - +this.state.expense;
}
```

This code is working:

```
handleIncomeChange(e) {
    const income = e.target.value;
    this.state.resultMonth = +income - +this.state.expense;
    this.setState({income: e.target.value});
}
```

Not sure if I understand concept of React.JS state correctly. Definitely don't understand why first code don't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the state directly using `this.state =` (except during state initialisation).  Make all your state modifications using the `setState` API.

For example:

```
handleIncomeChange(e) {
  const newIncome = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
    income: newIncome,
    resultMonth: newIncome - this.state.expense
  });
}
```

---

*Update: based on the codepen and problem described by OP in comments below.*

You could do something like the following to solve the issue of reusability.

```
handleDataChange(income, expense) {
  this.setState({
    income: income,
    expense: expense,
    resultMonth: income - expense
  });
}

handleIncomeChange(e) {
  const newIncome = e.target.value;
  this.handleDataChange(newIncome, this.state.expense);
}

handleExpenseChange(e) {
  const newExpense = e.target.value;
  this.handleDataChange(this.state.income, newExpense);
}
```

Comment: `handleIncomeChange(e) {
  const newIncome = e.target.value;
  this.setState({
   income: newIncome,
   resultMonth: newIncome - this.state.expense
  });

  this.showinfo()
 }
 showinfo() {
  console.log(resultMonth);
 }`

If I use this function it's still "one step behind". Do you know how to properly do this?

Comment: `this.setState` is not guaranteed to execute synchronously, therefore if you try to log the `this.state` directly after calling `this.setState` you are not guaranteed to see the updated results.  In stead you need to access the updated state via the `render()` or through one of the lifecycle methods (e.g. `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)`).  What are you trying to do in `showInfo`? If you update your question with this I can make a recommendation.  Most likely you can handle this in the `render()`.

Comment: `showInfo` is only for testing purpose. I want to achieve form with many inputs where every change fire a function which does math operation with updated values. Something like: `calculate {this.state.expense - this.state.income + this.state.tax}`

Comment: Hmmm, I think you might be overlooking a few of the React fundamentals in regards to state -> render cycles.  If you post a full component example I can try to make a recommendation.

Comment: Thanks! I prepared this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWWazj it's working but there will be problem in future when I have to use lot of inputs and advanced math logic. It should be in one function instead of duplicating code (setting state of `resultMonth`)  in every changeHandler..

Comment: Totally possible, updating my answer.